# How do I replace NaN with 0 or "No Input Found"

Tags: javascript, html, nan

I am trying to replace the result of NaN in my calculator result with 0 or the words "No Input Found".

Here is the Javascript Code for the Section.

```
// Calculator Functions JavaScript STARTS here
function add() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = num1 + num2;
    }

    function subtract() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = num1 - num2;
    }

    function multiply() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = num1 * num2;
    }

    function divide() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("result").textContent = num1 / num2;
    }
// Calculator Functions JavaScript ENDS here
```

Here is my HTML code for the section.

```
<div id="container">

<h2>Basic Web Calculator</h2>
<input class="instbtn" type="text" id="num1" placeholder="Enter Numbers Here">
<input class="instbtn" type="text" id="num2" placehodler="Enter Numbers Here">
<br>

<button class="calbtn" onclick="add()">Add (+)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="subtract()">Subtract (-)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="multiply()">Multiply (x)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="divide()">Divide (÷)</button>
<br>

<h3>Result: <span id="result"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that is checking for `NaN`.

Comment: you can check a value is a `NaN` or not using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), have you tried that?

Comment: @BagusTesa that doesn't work or maybe I am not doing it the right way.

Comment: @TimRoberts here is a screenshot of what my result is. https://prnt.sc/yTgPWh3kLofy
The "NaN" is what the result comes out as and I would like to change it to 0.

Comment: *"that doesn't work"* - can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I know what it will do.  What I'm saying is you haven't done ANYTHING here to try to solve this problem.    YOU need to make a good effort, then come to us if it doesn't work.

Comment: why use input type text for number input instead of using input type number? If you would program correctly, you would never get into a spot that you face NaN

Comment: Why don't you use number input fields instead of text input fields, and set the "required" attribute? That will ensure the user enter numbers in those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple codes and still failed.. until I did the most simplest of things. I added || 0; at the end of the answer code line.

```js
function add() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("answer").textContent = num1 + num2 || 0;
    }

    function subtract() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("answer").textContent = num1 - num2 || 0;
    }

    function multiply() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("answer").textContent = num1 * num2 || 0;
    }

    function divide() {
        var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("answer").textContent = num1 / num2 || 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">

<h2>Basic Web Calculator</h2>
<input class="instbtn" type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Enter Numbers Here">
<input class="instbtn" type="number" id="num2" placehodler="Enter Numbers Here">
<br>

<button class="calbtn" onclick="add()">Add (+)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="subtract()">Subtract (-)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="multiply()">Multiply (x)</button>
<button class="calbtn" onclick="divide()">Divide (÷)</button>
<br>

<h3>The Answer Is: <span id="answer"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
function add() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 0;
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 0;
  const result = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
}

function subtract() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 0;
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 0;
  const result = num1 - num2;
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
}

function multiply() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 1;
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 1;
  const result = num1 * num2;
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
}

function divide() {
  var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 0;
  var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 1;
  if (num2 === 0) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Cannot Divide by 0";
  } else {
    const result = num1 / num2;
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = result;
  }
}
```